# My audio does not work. What can I do?

Tags: sound, kubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa

I tried to rescan the audio cards with `alsactl` but got an configuration error.

```
alsactl: state_lock:125: file /var/lib/alsa/asound.state lock error: File exists
alsactl: load_state:1683: Cannot open /var/lib/alsa/asound.state for reading: File exists
alsa-lib main.c:1021:(snd_use_case_mgr_open) error: failed to import hw:0 (empty configuration)
Found hardware: "HDA-Intel" "Realtek ALC295" "HDA:10ec0295,103c8362,00100002 HDA:8086280b,80860101,00100000" "0x103c" "0x8362"
Hardware is initialized using a generic method
```

How can I fix it I cannot restore it even after restart

Comment: You need to call *restore* with root privilege: `sudo alsactl restore`.